# Delegate method of the UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am new to IOS development.. I have a requirement in which i need to save a numeric data entered on the UITextField on click of the return button of the IPHone simulator Keypad.. Please help me and tell me that which delegate method is used to save the data entered in he TextField on click of the return button..

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What Have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And please read [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

This will get fired up when the textfield resigns when you click the return button. You can then do whatever you want to do with the entered text.